# Login using facebook and user can chat using locations

Tags: android, facebook

i was going through Q[uickBlox Developers (API docs, code samples, SDK](http://quickblox.com/developers/Overview#API_User)).. i Just wanted to know is it possible to log in through facebook and pull the user information and then user can have location based chat.. i dont want user to sign up.. they should login using facebook and get their information (name, gender, sex preference from fb ).. I need some advice ..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can signin using FaceBook account.Read this official tutorial for FaceBook Integration [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

**iOS:**

1) Login through Facebook

```
[QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" delegate:self];

...

// QuickBlox queries delegate
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{

    // success result
    if(result.success){

        // User Login
        if([result isKindOfClass:QBUUserLogInResult.class]){
            QBUUserLogInResult *res = (QBUUserLogInResult *)result;

            // Your Facebook access token
            NSString *accessToken = res.socialProviderToken;
            NSString *expiresAt = res.socialProviderTokenExpiresAt;

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Errors=%@", result.errors); 
    }
}
```

2) Retrieve your Facebook profile

```
 NSString *meQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@", accessToken];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[meQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


 // perform request
 NSURLResponse **response = nil;
 NSError **error = nil;
 NSData *resultData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:response error:error];

 // set body
 NSString *bodyAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

 // This is your Facebook profile as dictionary
 NSDictionary *me = [parser objectWithString:bodyAsString];

 [bodyAsString release];
 [parser release];
```

3) Location based chat - look at Location sample http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-location_users-ios - it's simple location based chat, just is it after login

**Android**

Did you see

[MapChat sample](http://quickblox.com/developers/SuperSample_%28Map_Chat_code_sample%29_Android) ?

This sample contains all features you need

Comment: ya i have seen SuperSample (Map Chat code sample) Android, but problem is its not free(only upto 5 gb is free) and i am making commercial app so i am planning to deploy my server.

Comment: Do you use lots of Contents in your app?

Comment: Problem is I amnot making app for myself.. I am developing for my Client and he wants to depoly his server.. Currently i am working on integration of Facebook.. I imported fb sdk and i am getting this error... [2012-10-04 17:59:58 - com.facebook.android.Example] Unable to resolve target 'android-3'
[2012-10-04 17:59:58 - com.facebook.stream.App] Unable to resolve target 'android-3'
[2012-10-04 17:59:58 - com.facebook.android.tests.Tests] Unable to resolve target 'android-3'.. do i need to download android 1.5 sdk or is there any other solution